Black screen after selecting the booting option,Cannot change the resolution.Windows 10/Ubuntu Dual boot
I try to boot in Ubuntu and it shows me a black screen after I select the booting option,but If I got to recovery mode and resume I can boot and I get to the desktop where I can do everything except changing my resolution and refresh rate.I tried everything.I have a AMD Raiden as my video card and I also have Windows 10 on the same Partition.My system is(inxi -G):
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Ellesmere [Radeon RX
    470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] driver: N/A
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.11 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting,radeon,vesa unloaded: fbdev
    dri: swrast gpu: N/A resolution: 1024x768~60Hz
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: kms_swrast,swrast
    platforms: gbm,x11,surfaceless,device
  API: OpenGL v: 4.5 vendor: mesa v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.1
    renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 17.0.6 256 bits)

I tried Linux mint Ubuntu and now Lubuntu,all had the same issue.

Which Ubuntu did you install? What is the output of inxi -G? Add the answers into your question (not the comments)

Here u go sir,thank you for trying to help me I really apreciate it.

I can't give an answer without knowing your Ubuntu Version (such as 22.04 or 24.04). This is usually the first info for all questions in this forum. But my educated guess is that you need to install the Radeon drivers. There are many answers about it in this forum.
